# RichTextMode attribute is ignored when applied

Tags: content-type, rich-text, field-definition

In my solution, I have defined a custom Field and Content Type. The field is defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{5f4f08ad-7f5b-4d5d-879c-50b417acae3d}"
    Name="TaskActionComment"
    StaticName="TaskComment"
    DisplayName="Comment"
    Type="Note"
    RichText="TRUE"
    RichTextMode="FullHtml"
    Required="FALSE"
    Group="Knowledge Base Article Columns">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

And the Content Type is defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Workflow Task (0x010801) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010801003EE4B5580C5846B6BE74BFC41A663388"
    Name="Technical Review Task"
    ...
    Inherits="FALSE"
    Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      ...
      <FieldRef ID="{5f4f08ad-7f5b-4d5d-879c-50b417acae3d}"
      Name="ActionComment" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      ...
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

When I use the UI to confirm the definitions after deployment, the field looks correct.

[image]

But when I add the Content Type to my Tasks list and go look at the column definition for the list I get

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The field XML looks good.. Can you try to delete the delete the content type and column, and then redeploy your solution?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri -- I had already tried re-deploying and even rebooted the system in-between deployments. I found the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It looks like it was a SharePoint "retention" issue. It seems that retracting a solution **does not** truly remove everything.

Using **SharePoint Manager 2013**, I was able to see that the `Comment` field was still defined in the `List` even though the `Content Types` were removed from the List and the solution was retracted. In addition, when the solution gets re-deployed, SharePoint sees that the column already exists in the List and uses that previous definition instead of the defined attributes in the solution.

Go figure...

Comment: Yes retracting doesn't mean removing the Site Columns where they are used.. It's good between in case of Production site which has live data.. :)

Comment: I understand that...and it makes sense. But that should only apply if the list that "uses" it actually has any data in it. In my case, the list was empty. (And yes...both recycle bins were empty.) From a development stand-point, this makes it very, very difficult to code up my solution if I need to manually go in and delete each column after retracting it.

Comment: True, most of the time on Feature Deactivation.. I write code to delete the columns from the List as well :) Of course, remove this in Production..

Comment: Ahhh. I see. In my case I moved the list instance creation and content type additions to existing lists, from the SP solution to a PowerShell script. So I deploy from VS and then run my "Set Up" script. I also have a corresponding "Tear Down" script that is run before Retracting. I guess I need to add the Column removal to the "Tear Down" script too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to your custom field "TaskActionComment" as simply "ActionComment" in the content type definition. Amend the content type reference to the field to "TaskActionComment" and test again. Hope that's it!

Comment: Matching the name did not help. I found the solution and posted it.